# How to show history command terminal ubuntu when typing

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I want to show the history command on ubuntu
example: I used to command:

```
sudo apt-get update
apt-get remove xxx
```

Now I type "sudo" it will show "sudo apt-get update".

Comment: Have you tried `!sudo`, or if you're using the default line editor, <Ctrl R> `su`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand your question, but:

entering <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> at the command prompt will permit you to enter text that may be a fragment of a former command. As you enter this text, the *history function* will begin searching, and present a matching line at the command prompt.

If the current line is **not** what you're looking for, another <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> will fetch the next matching line.

The search will be done in order of most recently entered commands.

Once you've found the command you're looking for, a "side arrow" (<kbd>→</kbd>) will put you on the command line where you may edit the command.

Finally, if you want to get out of the search gracefully, <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> will take care of that on most systems.

Comment: Thanks man , I tried your `ctrl  r  , ctrl g , ->`

Answer (score 0):

Just type in terminal : `history`

**Command :** history - It will display all list of commands you have used so far

Or

make use of up arrow and down arrow key to go to previous command and new command